Jest + Promise.all. Function was called multiple times with expected params
I'm performing multiple different calls - to get data from an external API.
const results = Promise.all([collectDataForA, collectDataForB, collectDataForC])

each of these promises: collectDataForA, collectDataForB, collectDataForC
calls a nested function fetchData() just once with specific params (let's say collectDataForA calls it with param "paramForCollectDataForA", collectDataForB calls it with "paramForCollectDataForB", collectDataForC it with "paramForCollectDataForC").
I can mock/stub or spy on fetchData() function.
I have to make sure that fetchData() function was called exactly 3 times with each of the params I've mentioned above.
I can not use just something like this:
expect(fetchDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedParam) 

because I have multiple calls of the same function, plus I can't anticipate the calls order, since I'm using Promise.all
I could push the call arguments to an array (in my spy) and then at the end to check that it contains all the params sets that I was expecting, but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution

You can also assert that fetchDataSpy.mock.calls should be an array containing 3 entries and describe the arguments, but I think asserting that it should have been called 3 times and specifying the exact arguments with .toHaveBeenCalledWith is elegant enough

@Teneff, thank you! fetchDataSpy.mock.calls is pretty helpful in my case. I don't think I can use .toHaveBeenCalledWith without knowing all the params that will be passed - I know the value only of one param that will be passed to the function in my case and can't predict the rest

in an isolated, controlled environment you should always be able to "predict" the rest, but you can also use expect.anything()
